# Homotopy initial functors and Grothendieck construction

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory

I am studying homotopy colimits and its relation to Grothendieck construction. It is well known that if given a homotopy terminal functor $i: I\rightarrow J$(i.e. for each element $j\in J$ the preimage $i^{-1}(\geq j)$ is contractible) then we have a weak equivalence from $hocolim_{I}i^* F$ to $hocolim_J F$ for any functor $F :J\rightarrow \text{CW-complexes}$. As for Grothendieck constructions we have a similar phenomenon, given any functor $F:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow Cat$ and a homotopy terminal functor $i:I\rightarrow J$ then there is a weak homotopy equivalence between Grothendieck constructions $\int_{J} i^* F$ and $\int_{J} F$ after taking geometric realizations since the geometric realization of Grothendieck construction is weak equivalent to the associated homotopy colimits.

However, I was wondering in the situation of Grothendieck construction, if we replace the homotopy terminal functor $i$ by a homotopy initial functor $i: I\rightarrow J$, is it still ture that the associated Grothendieck constructions are weak equivalent?

I have a rough argument as follows but it might be wrong. If the functor $i$ is a homotopy initial functor, we can consider the opposite categoies for Grothendieck constructions $\int_{J} i^* F$ and $\int_{J} F$ which are $\int_{J^{op}} i^* F^{op}$ and $\int_{J^{op}} F^{op}$. Then the associated functor from $\int_{J^{op}} i^* F^{op}$ to $\int_{J^{op}} F^{op}$ is weak equivaelnt after taking geometric realization since the  opposite functor $i^{op}:I^{op}\rightarrow J^{op}$ is a homotopy terminal functor. And since the opposite category is weak equivalent to the original one after taking geometric realizations we conclude that if $i$ is a homotopy initial functor then the associated Grothendieck constructions $\int_{J} i^* F$ and $\int_{J} F$ are weak equivalent.

I believe at least there is no such statement for homotopy colimits, so the above argument for Grothendieck constructions might be wrong. If it is not true in general, do we have some creteria when the two Grothendieck constructions are weak equivalent if $i$ is homotopy initial?

Comment: Perhaps it would be good to understand the non-homotopy situation first. If you have a (co)initial functor then it induces isomorphisms of limits. Dually, if you have a (co)final functor then it induces isomorphisms of colimits. The Grothendieck construction is a kind of homotopy colimit, and as you say, a homotopy (co)final functor induces weak homotopy equivalences of Grothendieck constructions. There is no reason to expect anything for a Grothendieck constructions and homotopy (co)initial functor.